# Is it possible to access s3 private bucket objects in Ec2 instance without using Cloud font distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm planning to host Angular client side development files in AWS S3 (e.g. images/,fonts/,js/) as a private bucket (e.g. not allowing the objects to access public) and a backend Docker java application in an EC2 instance, under a VPC.

- Is it possible to access S3 private bucket objects in Ec2 instance, without using CDN, and without mounting S3 Bucket as a file system / folder in EC2 instance?

Once the user is authorized through backend application, it should render the UI pages from S3.

Comment: Your question says you want to access the files from EC2, but the last sentence in your question makes it sound like you want each user's browser to access the files on S3. Are you planning on having EC2 proxy all requests for the files?

Answer (score 0):

Attach an IAM role to your instance that has permission to retrieve files from your S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an S3 endpoint for your VPC.

> A VPC endpoint enables you to privately connect your VPC to supported
>   AWS services and VPC endpoint services powered by PrivateLink without
>   requiring an internet gateway, NAT device, VPN connection, or AWS
>   Direct Connect connection

[Endpoint for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html)